# why can't I have awk group statements in the if clause only if else clause is present

Tags: awk, grammar, conditional-statements

If this is good `awk` syntax

```
awk '{if (0) {print""}}'
```

and so is this

```
awk '{if (0) print""; else print ""}'
```

, then why is this bad syntax??

```
awk '{if (0) {print""}; else print ""}'
```

Comment: Just remove the semicolon after `{print ""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the awk conditional syntax is (among others)

```
if condition compound-statement else compound-statement
```

Just as in C, by the way. This makes

```
if condition compound-statement ';' else compound-statement
```

an error.